# Append data to array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
double b[3] = {3,3,4};
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
  cout<<b[i]<<" "<<endl;
}

int sum = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    sum += b[i];
  } cout<<"\n"<<sum<<endl;


for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
  double norm_b = b[i]/sum;
  cout<<norm_b<<endl;
}
```

Result:

```
0.3                                                                                                                     
0.3                                                                                                                     
0.4
```

How to insert data (norm_b) to array, like `append` in Python?

Comment: You cannot change size of embedded array, use `std::vector` instead

Comment: You want a `std::vector`, not a C-style array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys

Solved

Update:

```
#include <vector>

  vector<double> vec;
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
      vec.push_back(b[i]/sum);
      cout<<vec[i]<<endl;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The size of an array never changes through its lifetime. As such, there is no way to insert (nor to remove) elements.

What can be done instead, is to allocate an array dynamically, and upon insertion, allocate a bigger array, copy the elements from the old one, which can then be deallocated - or at least that is the general idea; I've skipped implementation details. Such data structure is called a resizable array. The standard library has an implementation of the resizable array: `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you mention Python, then there are better library classes and algorithms that are closer to what you might be used from Python.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

void main() {
    std::vector<double> b{3, 3, 4}; // Init vector

    // If compiler supports C++11 you can use range-for
    for (auto value : b)
    {
        std::cout << value << " " << std::endl;
    }

    double sum = std::accumulate(b.begin(), b.end(), 0); // sum b, sum should be double, not int?
    std::cout << "\n"
              << sum << std::endl;

    std::vector<double> norm_b(b.size()); // initialize norm_b with b.size() elements
    size_t idx = 0;
    std::generate(norm_b.begin(), norm_b.end(), [&b, &idx, &sum]() {
        return b[idx++] / sum;
    });

    // Again range-for if C++11
    for (auto value : norm_b)
    {
        std::cout << value << " " << std::endl;
    }
}
```

There are a number of things in this code that you should look up if you don't fully understand:

- Various way to initiliaze a `std::vector` (initializer list - braced initialization, count constructor etc)
- std::vector iterators
- `std::accumulate`
- `std::generate`
- lambdas
- range-for
- iterators based for (not used in the code above)

Answer (score 1):

You can "append" a value only to a data structure that can dynamically grow in size. A c-like array if fixed size. You can try to use a `std::vector`which has a `push_back` method, equivalent to python append method.

note: Instead of C-like array, consider to use `std::array` which is part of c++ STL and let you use STL algorithm on it.

Comment: why are you speaking about `std::array` when the goal is to resize ? this is disturbing

Comment: @bruno giving the fixed size array in the first line. clearly `std::vector` is the right solution. I mention `std::array` as an alternative to the declaration in the first line

Comment: I think  you must be more clear, like *When the size if constant instead of C-like ...*

Comment: You are right @bruno :) Also the question was not so clear (if you start allocating a fixed size array, it make no much sense to me to talk about dynamic sized vectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use vector for append data as more as you like.For use vector you have to include a header file name vector.Here the code below:
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
  {
     //declare a vector first

    vector<double>v;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) 
    {
        sum += b[i];
    }
     for(int i=0;i<3;i++) 
    {
     vec.push_back(b[i]/sum);
     cout<<vec[i]<<" "<<endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```